# Book about a magical land, dragons, magical weapons, swords. People turning into dragons

Tags: story-identification, books

The book starts off with a boy who sees a girl turning into a dragon after school, then people come to his house, he goes with the girl and her dad, who turns into a dragon and flies them to a magical land for him to get training and a greatsword chooses him.